# What is Redhawk DEPLOYMENT_ROOT?

Tags: redhawksdr

In redhawk 2.1.0 IDE, everytime I drag a component to chalkboard the console displays the warning

**WARN  PropertySet_impl:140 - Property: RH::DEPLOYMENT_ROOT is not defined, ignoring it!!**

What is this DEPLOYMENT_ROOT property? Which value should it be set to? How do I do that?
I'm trying to use redhawk in ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is due to using an older Core Framework version than IDE version. The IDE provides the RH::DEPLOYMENT_ROOT property but the Core Framework does not know what that property is. The RH::DEPLOYMENT_ROOT property was introduced in 2.1.0, and is required when launching components in the 2.1-series. You can either ignore the error, or you should match your IDE and Core Framework versions.